# Buffer overflow appeared before it is expected

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to take a control over a stack overflow. First, here is an example of C code I compiled on an x32 VM Linux (`gcc -fno-stack-protector -ggdb -o first first.c`),

```
#include "stdio.h"

int CanNeverExecute()
{
    printf("I can never execute\n");
    return(0);
}

void GetInput()
{
    char buffer[8];

    gets(buffer);
    puts(buffer);
}

int main()
{
    GetInput();
    return(0);
}
```

Then debugger (intel flavor): dump of assembler code for function `GetInput`:

```
0x08048455 <+0>:    push   ebp
0x08048456 <+1>:    mov    ebp,esp
0x08048458 <+3>:    sub    esp,0x28
0x0804845b <+6>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0x10]
```

Here we can see that sub esp, 0x28 reserves 40 bytes for a buffer variable (Right?).
`CanNeverExecute` function is located in address `0x0804843c`.
So, in order to run `CanNeverExecute` function, I need to put 40 bytes into buffer variable, then goes 8 bytes for stored base pointer and then 8 bytes of return pointer I want to change.

So, I need a string of 48 ASCII symbols plus `\x3c\x84\x04\x08` in the end (address of the `CanNeverExecute` function). That is in theory. But In practice I need only 20 bytes before address of the return pointer:

```
~/hacktest $ printf "12345678901234567890\x3c\x84\x04\x08" | ./first
12345678901234567890..
I can never execute
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Why does it need only 20 bytes instead of 48? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, your assembly is 32-bit. Saved EBP and return address are 4 bytes each.

Second, the `buffer` variable does not start at stack top (ESP) - it starts at ebp-0x10. Which is 20 bytes away from the return address. 0x10 is 16 bytes, then 4 more for the saved EBP.

Answer (score 2):

If You take bigger part of dissassembly You will see:

```
08048445 <GetInput>:
8048445:    55                      push   %ebp
8048446:    89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
8048448:    83 ec 28                sub    $0x28,%esp
804844b:    8d 45 f0                lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
804844e:    89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
8048451:    e8 9a fe ff ff          call   80482f0 <gets@plt>
8048456:    8d 45 f0                lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
8048459:    89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
804845c:    e8 9f fe ff ff          call   8048300 <puts@plt>
8048461:    c9                      leave  
8048462:    c3                      ret
```

ebp is saved, esp is moved to ebp, then 40 is subtracted from esp (stack frame, as you wrote), 
but pointer to buffer is passed to gets via eax register, and eax is loaded with ebp-0x10!

```
lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
```

So You need only 20 bytes to overflow the buffer (16 reserved + 4 for stored base pointer on 32-bit system)